# shadowbox - open inline element

Tags: javascript, jquery, inline, shadowbox

I am using shadowbox and jQuery.

I have it opening on page load fine.

What I want to do is.

Have the shadowbox open up and show a form where the user can enter their email address.

I then want to submit said form via ajax.

I am dumping the form on the page wrapped in a hidden div with the id of `#dialog`.

My question is.

How can I get the shadowbox to be opened automatically with an inline element?

Comment: So, you want someone to click on, for example, a link (`a` element) and have the shadowbox become visible?

Comment: No, I want to open the shadowbox at page load.

Comment: IF you want it to be shown on page load, why not just use CSS and `display: block;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Shadowbox.open method.

```
Shadowbox.open({
    content:    '<div id="welcome-msg">Welcome to my website!</div>',
    player:     "html",
    title:      "Welcome",
    height:     350,
    width:      350
});
```

You will need to change some of the params to get it to use the inline content.