# how to automatically open Shadowbox on window/page load

Tags: javascript, html, image, shadowbox

Me using [Shadowbox](http://www.shadowbox-js.com/) and its working fine.
But I dont like to open it after clicking on image (href), need to open it automatocally on pageload.

What can I change to do it?

Here is **HTML**

```
 <div id="images">
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/1.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -1</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/2.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -2</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/3.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -3</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/4.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -4</a>
                    <a href="resources/certified_training/5.png" rel="shadowbox[certifiedtraining];width=510;height=372">Image -5</a>
                </div>
```

And here **JavaScript**

```
window.onload = function () {
             loadShadowbox();
         };

function loadShadowbox() {
Shadowbox.init({
            showOverlay: false
        });

        window.Shadowbox.setDimensionsOld = window.Shadowbox.setDimensions;
        window.Shadowbox.setDimensions = function (height, width, maxHeight, maxWidth, topBottom, leftRight, padding, preserveAspect) {
            var S = window.Shadowbox;
            window.Shadowbox.setDimensionsOld(height, width, maxHeight, maxWidth, topBottom, leftRight, padding, preserveAspect);
            window.Shadowbox.dimensions.top = 340;
            window.Shadowbox.dimensions.left = 430;
            return window.Shadowbox.dimensions;
        }
```

Comment: `window.onload = function() { Shadowbox.open(); }`?

Comment: Check this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5671583/shadowbox-open-inline-element

Comment: i dont know how to use it with my images in hrefs....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You atually initialize a Shadowbox on window load, but not opening it. Once done, you end the `function loadShadowbox`, Instead open the Shadowbox towards the end.

**EDIT:**

I have modified the code. I actually missed a closed brace.

```
function loadShadowbox() {
    Shadowbox.init({
        showOverlay: false
    });

    window.Shadowbox.setDimensionsOld = window.Shadowbox.setDimensions;
    window.Shadowbox.setDimensions = function (height, width, maxHeight, maxWidth, topBottom, leftRight, padding, preserveAspect) {
        var S = window.Shadowbox;
        window.Shadowbox.setDimensionsOld(height, width, maxHeight, maxWidth, topBottom, leftRight, padding, preserveAspect);
        window.Shadowbox.dimensions.top = 340;
        window.Shadowbox.dimensions.left = 430;
        return window.Shadowbox.dimensions;
    }

window.Shadowbox.open();    //Add this line
}  //This is where your `function loadShadowbox()` ends.
```

Comment: i did it like you said. but the deal is, getting slideshow opened just after clicking on a href and not automatically by pageload.

Comment: Have changed the line where the open statement is added.

Comment: Still the same..... dont understand.... why this shadowbox doesnt starts automatically........ maybe its a false usage of  <a href...??